# In WDIO, what makes the Spec Reporter report a question mark?

Tags: javascript, specifications, webdriver-io, wdio

Whilst running WDIO tests on the command line (using [Spec reporter](https://webdriver.io/docs/spec-reporter/)), on one test run, I managed to make it report a '?" in the command line output. Something like this:

```
[Chrome 100.0.4896.60 darwin #0-0]    ✖ test1
[Chrome 100.0.4896.60 darwin #0-0]    ? test2
```

I don't remember how many tests passed or how many failed - just that there was at least one question mark in the column where I usually find ticks or crosses.

I saw that the test had no tests in it - immediately thought that was the secret, but I restructured the code, and was never able to reproduce the output since.

Does anyone know how to make a WDIO test result in a question mark?

I thought it might have been caused by a time out - but I forced a time out ([using this example](https://webdriver.io/docs/timeouts/) ), and saw that it results in an 'x' - and not a '?'

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use one of the 'skip' functionalities:
eg  this.skip()